# Multiple location maps in php

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-markers

In php I want to show the multiple location in map. its working fine for me single address using  jquery.auto-geocoder.js . But for multiple location address display in my maps.

Do you have any ideas?????

```
<section>
  <article>
    <form>
      <div class="full">
        <input type="hidden" id="location" value="<?php echo $address?>">
      </div>
    </form>
  </article>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Keyvalue&libraries=places"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo JS_DIR; ?>jquery.auto-geocoder.js'></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#location').autoGeocoder();
});
</script>
```

This is for single address . looking for multiple address not latitude and longitude

Comment: Show your code here to get  a better answer

Comment: Please tell me the all address in single map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `id` to `class` and use the class selector:

```
<section>
  <article>
    <form>
      <div class="full">
        <input type="hidden" class="location" value="<?php echo $address1;?>">
        <input type="hidden" class="location" value="<?php echo $address2;?>">
        <input type="hidden" class="location" value="<?php echo $address3;?>">
      </div>
    </form>
  </article>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Keyvalue&libraries=places"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo JS_DIR; ?>jquery.auto-geocoder.js'></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('.location').autoGeocoder();
});
</script>
```

Comment: but i was showed in different maps but i want show all address in one single map